# Using cucumber to check page titles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, acceptance-testing

**Feature**

```
Scenario: As a user that has not signed in I want to be able to sign up for provisioner
        Given I am not logged in
        When I go to the home page
        And click on the "Sign Up" button
        Then I should be on the page with the title: "Sign Up"
        When I provide valid information
        And click the "Submit" button
        Then I should see "Account is being created and verified, you will receive an   email with instructions once account has been approved"
        And the application should send the administrator an email
        And I should be redirected to the home page as an anonymous user
```

**Steps**

```
When /^I go to the home page$/ do
  visit root_path
end

When /^click on the "([^"]*)" button$/ do |page_name|
  click_link page_name
end

Then /^I should be on the page with the title: "([^"]*)"$/ do |page_title|
  response.should have_selector('title', :content => "#{page_title}")
end
```

**Error**

```
expected css "title" to return something (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

It fails at the **Then** step, however the page does render with the title: "Sign Up" when I manually go to it. I want it to make sure it's going to the right place in the test. How do I have it check?

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Never mind — if you are, try @Bohdan Pohorilets's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

`page.should have_css('head title', :text => title)`

Comment: I used the page.should have_selector('title', :content =>) and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: This requires rspec.

Answer (score 3):

Since 2.1 you can do that:

`expect(page).to have_title "my_title"`

Comment: This requires that you are using rspec.

Answer (score 0):

It might happen because by default capybara selector is set to `CSS` try change it to

```
response.should have_xpath('//title', :text => "#{page_title}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cucumber-rails gem, try using

```
assert page.has_title?(page_title), "page has title of '#{page.title}'"
```